# jQuery deffered resolve promise

Tags: jquery, promise, wrapper, web-sql, deferred

I walk with my head into a wall each time i try to do some async calls on dynamic generated content. (**i am still learning**)

This time i use html5sql.js plugin where i run several calls as within the code below.
I thought i finally managed how to use promises when i saw my results coming back in the console.log in another function.
Then i spend a day to figure out why i could not access my objects from the returned results... HUH?
So i had to use the old bad-practice trickery "setTimeout", but i do not want that anymore.... so let's come to the code where i attempted to do it right.....

```
//We going to fetch all products from the basket corresponding the customers_id.
//The returned array will hold all products data and if the product has attributes it will be returned inside the array.
function restore_contents() {

    var content = $.Deferred();

    var restored_contents = {}; 


    html5sql.process(
        [
            {
                "sql": "SELECT products_id, customers_basket_quantity FROM customers_basket WHERE customers_id = ? ",
                "data": [1],
                "success": function(transaction, results, rows){
                    $.each(rows, function(index, row){
                        if(typeof restored_contents[row.products_id] == 'undefined'){
                            restored_contents[row.products_id] = {};
                        }
                        restored_contents[row.products_id] = {qty : row.customers_basket_quantity, attributes : {}};
                    });

                    //console.log(products_array);
                    populateAttributesArray();
                }
            }                   

        ]
    );          


    function populateAttributesArray(){

        $.each(restored_contents, function(products_id){

            product_id = tep_get_prid(products_id);

            html5sql.process(
                [
                    {
                        "sql": "select p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_model, p.products_image, p.products_weight, p.products_tax_class_id from products p, products_description pd where p.products_id = ? and pd.products_id = p.products_id and pd.language_id = ?",
                        "data": [product_id, 1],
                        "success": function(transaction, results, productsData){

                            restored_contents[products_id]['products'] = productsData[0];


                        }                       
                    },
                    {
                        "sql": "SELECT products_options_id, products_options_value_id FROM customers_basket_attributes WHERE customers_id = ? and products_id = ?",
                        "data": [1, products_id],
                        "success": function(transaction, results, attributesData){

                            $.each(attributesData, function(index, attributes){
                                //  console.log(attributes);
                                restored_contents[products_id]['attributes'][attributes.products_options_id] = attributes.products_options_value_id;

                            });

                        }
                    }
                ]
            );//End html5sql.process

        });//End each           


        content.resolve(restored_contents);


    }

    return content.promise();

}
```

Then within another function i run the above :

```
function showCart() {

    $.when( restore_contents() ).done(function(content) {
        console.log( restore_contents ); //All content shows

        $.each(content, function(index, value){ 
            //some code but objects returned not accessible????
        });
   }); //End $.when
}
```

I try to find the answer on the net for my particular problem.
I just cannot figure it out how to write it correctly for my purposes. I only understand it a bit.

Comment: that code is still using setTimeout "trickery", I thought you said you *attempted to do it right*

Comment: Yes, that would be without the setTimeout encapsed `content.resolve(restored_contents);`